# What do you mean by a model is adequate?

Tags: regression, linear, goodness-of-fit

I'm learning about regression and stumbled upon this part where we check the accuracy of the model. In order to do that, we do an F test with the null hypothesis stating that the model equation is adequate and the alternative saying not adequate.
I know this is a simple question but what does it mean that a model is adequate?
Does lack of fit mean the same as model is not adequate?

Comment: Where did you stumble upon this?  Is it from a book?  (What book?)  Are you referring to a lack of fit test?

Comment: @gung - Reinstate Monica
It is my professor's notes. I mainly want to know what do you mean by "model is adequate". And additionally if the lack of fit test is basically testing that